# Selenium methods which can be used to upload picture/file when sendkeys and javascript executor are not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

There is an upload field but its not an input type, Sendkeys and JS executor does not work there.

Robot class worked perfectly but since this might fail on diff screen resolutions so would want to avoid any third party and check for a different automation approach using selenium methods.

Tried sendkeys and below code but it did not work-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        WebElement chooseFile = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("FileUpload1")));
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='visible'", chooseFile);
        chooseFile.sendKeys(path);`
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", uploadBtn);
```

Comment: It'll depend on the site and what events it's listening to in order to trigger the upload.  It'd help if you included the markup of the DOM when you run the robot.  (right-click on browser, choose "inspect", and copy/paste relevant markup into your question.)

Comment: The problem here is chooseFile has a hidden input tag so when I try to locate it , it throws element not intractable error